# Why are the melting and boiling points of the group 1 metals lower than the group 2 metals in the same period?

Tags: periodic-trends, melting-point

I thought it was because the group 1 metals are smaller than the group 2 metals but the answer sheet says it's because there are more valence electrons and a stronger positive charge in group 2 metals. But why does it matter if there's more valence electrons and a stronger positive charge?

Answer (score 2):

In the photo, you can see that for Group $2$ metals, the cation is doubly positively charged, making the attraction stronger.

[image]

---

### Credits

The photo is from [Figure 12.20, Section 12.5, Principles of General Chemistry (v. 1.0)](http://2012books.lardbucket.org/books/principles-of-general-chemistry-v1.0/s16-05-correlation-between-bonding-an.html).

Comment: Is it doubly positively charged because there's more protons?

Comment: @Hamze partly. it is doubly positively charged because it is two electrons away from the stable octet state, so two electrons become delocalized.